Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. on react-hook-form unregister set state
i've got Maximum update depth exceeded aka "infinite loop" in my react-lifecycle, i've handled it with unmounted but my code still error.
this bellow is my current conditional code using react-hook-form:
  const ConditionZoneField = ({
    control,
    index,
    register,
    unregister,
    itemIndex
  }: {
    control: Control<FormValues>;
    index: number;
    register: UseFormRegister<FormValues>;
    unregister: UseFormUnregister<FormValues>;
    itemIndex: number;
  }) => {
    const output = useWatch({
      name: `zones.${index}.data.${itemIndex}.room`,
      control
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!output?.value || output?.value !== "other") {
        unregister(`zones.${index}.data.${itemIndex}.additional`)
      }

      // Cleanup function to be executed when the component is unmounted
      return () => {
        unregister(`zones.${index}.data.${itemIndex}.additional`);
      };
    }, [index, itemIndex, output, unregister]);

    return (
      <div className='w-full flex flex-col gap-3'>
        {(output?.value === "other") && (
          <Fragment>
            <input
              placeholder='Input zone or add the new one'
              className='w-full rounded-lg px-4 py-3 border focus:outline-none'
              {...register(`zones.${index}.data.${itemIndex}.additional`, {
                required: {
                  value: true,
                  message: "Please input your zone or the new one"
                }
              })}
            />
            {errors.zones?.[index]?.data?.[itemIndex]?.additional &&
              <div className='mb-2 text-red-500 text-xs'>{errors.zones?.[index]?.data?.[itemIndex]?.additional?.message as any}</div>
            }
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

i want to remove this infinite loop on useEffect lifecycle, Thank you :)

did you figure this out?
